# change Office 2013 to LTR

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013, right-to-left

I purchased Microsoft Office 2013 with Hebrew package (RTL language).

But I want to change the toolbars to be left-to-right like the rest of the world...

Does someone know how to do it?

[image: The Hebrew toolbar - RTL]

Comment: You should be able to simply purchase install a different `language pack` or download and install a different `interface pack` [here[(http://products.office.com/en-us/language-packs/microsoft-office-language-options-multilingual-support)

Comment: @Ramhound, I looked in the interface languages, but English is not there! I guess English is already installed and I just have to switch to it, but I don't know how...?

Comment: English is a language pack so it costs money

Answer (score 0):

The "Microsoft Office Language Preferences" utility let you set the interface language and other relevant settings. See instructions [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162397%28v=office.15%29.aspx) (under "Use the Language Preferences tool to change language settings").